# In the Map box map anytime I zoom out and in the waypoints all turns into the black

Tags: mapbox

I am using Mapbox map. Version 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 5.9.0'.
when I am zoom out and zoom in its showing blank images on way points and its looking like blur map.

How to correct these issue on Mapbox Map?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it's only happening in the emulator, then it's a known bug: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/issues/561